# Excel: Formula To find a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with the following columns:

[image]

I need a formula that can give me the following result, taking into account the records that do exist and those that don't:

[image]

I try to look a lookup function but it does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: `MATCH()` or `XMATCH()` can be used to find. or `=MMULT(N(A2:A4=TOROW(B2:B3)),{1;1})` or `=ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A4,B2:B3))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `XMATCH()` or `MATCH()` or `MMULT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=IF(MMULT(N(A2:A4=TOROW(B2:B3)),{1;1}),"EXIST","NO EXIST")
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A4,B2:B3)),"EXIST","NO EXIST")
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$3,0)),"NOT EXIST","EXIST")
```

---